# Can't enable list even with "enable run-stop" poke

Tags: basic, c64, commodore, retro-computing

Well, I've downloaded an old non-English textual adventure, which of course, "for the sake of professionalism" have list disabled. Even after entering pokes for enabling "run-stop/restore" and for enabling "list" it continually questions for an input (in-game). I've tried to enter listing even on starting screen but it regards an emulated "run/stop-restore" just as any other button. "press any key" (just in our language...) .

Link with downloadable .prg:

http://retrospec.sgn.net/users/tomcat/yu/C64/MiscGames/Html/BezMilosti.php

P.S.: Because of auto-loading of .prg format when dragged over screen in V.I.C.E I've even made a new .d64 disk and as such, provoked the infamous "Loading. Ready." state. From that place I've entered pokes indeed.

P.S. 2: **I've posted a theme and thread about this problem under "scene" category on "lemon", the top-ranked site dedicated to commodore**:

***edit** (importing of the link):

https://www.lemon64.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=69043

Comment: You might want to cross-post this in https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Thanx Sir for advice. I'll copy paste whole thing there too.

Comment: @BillHileman Can you not advise users to cross-post? It's frowned upon on SE.

Comment: @wizzwizz Someone must have edited my original comment.  I never suggest "CROSS" post.  I'm sure I would have suggested that they POST it in retrocomputing.  Someone else probably thought they were improving my comment.

Comment: @BillHileman Nope; hasn't been edited. Not even by a moderator, who are the only people other than the original user who have the privileges to edit other posts. Unless it was a Stack Exchange employee who directly edited the database entry without adding in an edit history... but I think that's a bit far-fetched.

Comment: It would be, and I'll take your word for it.  I have no idea why I would have suggested a cross-post.  I certainly wasn't consciously typing that, but I'll own it.  Wouldn't be my first mistake on SE.